# How to compute the starting and ending of a lease period?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, parachain

For a given lease period, how can we know when the lease period starts and ends (as date time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Kusama and Polkadot - Given a lease period "x", you will need to retrieve the storage constants slots.leasePeriod and slots.leaseOffset. Then compute the height at which the lease period start this way :

```
x*leasePeriod + leaseOffset
```

And its end

```
(x+1)*leasePeriod + leaseOffset -1
```

Once you have the `heightStart` and `heightEnd` of your lease period "x", retrieve the head block (for example with `api.rpc.chain.getBlock();`).

If `heightStart` is lower or equal than the head block height, then retrieve the block which number is equal to heightStart (first by getting its hash `blockStartHash = this.api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(heightStart);`, then by getting the block using the hash : `startBlock = api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockStartHash);`. Now you have the timestamp (from startBlock properties) of the of the start of the lease period. You can do the same for the `heightEnd`.

If the `heightStart` or `heightEnd` is greater than the headBlock's number (height), then it is possible to *estimate* the timestamp of the lease period start (and/or end). To do so, you get the difference between the height and the head block's height. For example `diffBlock = heightStart - headBlockHeight` then multiple that value with the `MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK` constant value of the chain (for both Polkadot and Kusama it is 6000) and finally add it to the head block's timestamp to have a your estimatedLeasePeriodStartTimestamp (or ...End...).

Comment: FYI if you want to see when a future block is likely to come into existence then subscan has your back: https://polkadot.subscan.io/block/99999999